# How to prevent git vimdiff from opening files as read-only?

Tags: git, readonly, vimdiff, difftool

I'm trying to use vimdiff as a diff tool for Git but, for some reason, the files are always open in read-only mode. It makes sense for the original file but not for the ones that I have modified (since I haven't committed them yet).

This is my current .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
        tool = vimdiff
[merge]
        tool = vimdiff
[difftool]
        prompt = false
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's the default desired behaviour for vimdiff.  You can unset using `:set noro`.

Or in your .vimrc config, add this:

```
" Default to not read-only in vimdiff
set noro
```

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to set up vimdiff so that this option is always on?

Comment: In your vimrc file, construct the following line:
set noro

Comment: @Laurent, while I was going thro some help on vim, I found this URL (it might help you).  Please check the bottom of the page which says "Change read/only files to read/write when they are edited"  
URL : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer.  I guess this should be part of your vimrc configuration file.  Please update if this works fine..

Comment: thanks but actually the `noro` option is exactly what I was looking for, as I prefer being able to edit the diff by default (I often do some clean-up on the changed files before committing).

Comment: Would you consider expanding this answer to explain why it's the default desired behavior?

Comment: Read-only is not a default behavior of vimdiff. Try it: `vimdiff thisfile thatfile`. Git passes -R (Read-only mode) when invoking vimdiff. Is there a way to tell git to not do that?

Comment: What happens if you remove the read only option and accidentally edit a file in a previous commit?

Comment: @BAdhi _"What happens if you remove the read only option and accidentally edit a file in a previous commit?"_ It doesn't matter, because it's just a copy of the file in a tmp dir. It is impossible to change a previous git commit.

Comment: It's from the past though but still relevant. This answer has been chosen too fast as "The answer". As @bukzor has mentioned, what it says about vimdiff's default behaviour is not true. but it's luckily one of those non-100%-correct solutions which "works!". The complete answer could be the one from wisbucky bellow.

Comment: This is not a great answer.  This means any read only file you open will be marked as "not read only".

Answer (score 23):

The deafult command that git uses for vimdiff is: (found by inspecting process list)

```
vim -R -f -d -c "wincmd l" -c 'cd "$GIT_PREFIX"' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

You can override this (to not use `-R`, readonly mode) by setting the `difftool.vimdiff.cmd` variable.

```sh
$ git config --global difftool.vimdiff.cmd 'vim -f -d -c "wincmd l" -c '\''cd "$GIT_PREFIX"'\'' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
```

The quoting is tricky. I would copy-paste it.

Comment: this maybe some error, directly add "set noreadonly" in your vimrc file.

Comment: @Procras: I think you accidentally a word.

Comment: @alexis you still missed starting double quote for last word. please add it to make copy/paste safe for further users

Comment: @ZuBB yes!, thanks. I can't edit the old comment so I'll write it here again:  I just put `[difftool "vimdiff"] cmd = vim -f -d -c 'wincmd l' -c 'cd "$GIT_PREFIX"' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"` in ~/.gitconfig

Comment: Instead of removing it, I'd consider replacing the `-R` flag with the `-n` flag to allow writing, but disable swap files.
This makes recovery after crash impossible, but avoids weird errors & behavior when diffing files opened in other vim sessions.

Answer (score 9):

The reason this happens is because git invokes `vimdiff` with the `-R` (readonly) option. There are several solutions to be able to write to the file:

1. Use `:w!` in vim. That will force write even though it was opened as readonly.
2. You can edit `~/.gitconfig` to override the vimdiff command without `-R`

   ```
   [difftool "vimdiff"]
   cmd = vimdiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
   ```
3. You can edit `~/.vimrc` to always make vimdiff writeable. (This will affect all vimdiff, not just git.)

   ```
   if &diff
       set noreadonly
   endif
   ```

Comment: The first option is safe and simple.